# Как установить формат в Gmagick?

Tags: php, linux, apache2, apache-modules

Вот пытаюсь установить графическую библиотеку Gmagick.

Вроде бы установил. На компьютере перекодирует. А с помощью PHP ошибку.

> Uncaught GmagickException: No decode delegate for this image format

Пример кода:

```
  $imag = new Gmagick();
  $imag->read($file);
```

[image: Вот установленный пакет gmagick]

Вот что установлено. Я понимаю, что не установлен формат. Как его доустановить. В командной строке работает:

```
  for file in *.jpg
  do
   outfile=`basename $file .jpg`.tiff
    echo convert -verbose "'$file'" -rotate 90 \
      +profile "'*'" "'$outfile'"
  done > script.txt
  gm batch -echo on -feedback on script.txt
```

---

```
  GraphicsMagick 1.3.26 2017-07-04 Q8 http://www.GraphicsMagick.org/
Copyright (C) 2002-2017 GraphicsMagick Group.
Additional copyrights and licenses apply to this software.
See http://www.GraphicsMagick.org/www/Copyright.html for details.

  Feature Support:
  Native Thread Safe       yes
  Large Files (> 32 bit)   yes
  Large Memory (> 32 bit)  no
  BZIP                     no
  DPS                      no
  FlashPix                 no
  FreeType                 no
  Ghostscript (Library)    no
  JBIG                     no
  JPEG-2000                no
  JPEG                     no
  Little CMS               no
  Loadable Modules         no
  OpenMP                   no
  PNG                      no
  TIFF                     no
  TRIO                     no
  UMEM                     no
  WebP                     no
  WMF                      no
  X11                      no
  XML                      no
  ZLIB                     yes

Host type: i686-pc-linux-gnu

 Configured using the command:
  ./configure  '--without-perl' '--enable-shared' '--disable-openmp'

Final Build Parameters:
  CC       = gcc
  CFLAGS   = -g -O2 -Wall -pthread
  CPPFLAGS = 
  CXX      = g++
  CXXFLAGS = -pthread
  LDFLAGS  = 
  LIBS     = -lz -lm -lpthread
```

---

вот как ругается мой дистрибутив на пакеты

**sudo apt-get install libtool bzip2 zlib1g ghostscript gsfonts libfreetype6 libjpeg8 libjasper1 libpng12-0 libtiff5 graphicsmagick libgraphicsmagick1-dev**

Некоторые пакеты не возможно установить.Возможно,Вы просите не возможного,
или используете нестабильный дистрибутив, и запрашиваемые вами пакеты удалены из Incoming.
Следующая информация может помочь вам исправить ситуацию:

Пакеты которые имеют неудовлетворительные зависимости:
libgraphicsmagick1-dev : Зависимости (Depends): libxml2-devно он небудет установленн
Зависимости (Depends): libtiff-dev
Зависимости (Depends): libjbig-dev но он не будет установленн
Невозможно решить проблему у вас поломанные пакеты.

---

[image: grep]

Comment: У меня было очень похожее (правда пакеты все установились без проблем). Ответ был прост - картинка скачивалась неправильно. GMagick проверяет первые несколько байт, что бы определить тип, но он не мог (потому что там был перевод строки первым символом).

Comment: @KoVadim А как ты заливал фотки, и как решил проблему? К стати Ты же видел что gm version выдает на графические пекеты "NO" Причем на компьютере все перекодируется. и работает нормально.

Comment: писать Ты с большой буквы... В целом, я написал - у меня были битные картинки из за того, что их отдавал другой php скприпт неправильно. Рекомендую вначале решить проблему с зависимостями. А потом рассказать версию php - она должна быть не ниже 7.0.1

Comment: @KoVadim PHP 7.1.9-1, а как Ты поправил зависимости? Я делал вот так не помогло **sudo apt-get dist-upgrade**

Comment: у меня не было проблем с зависимостями в данном случае. Но вообще помогает `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: @KoVadim Вопрос. Скажи пожалуйста. что означет в ***gm version*** JPEG  no

Answer (score 0):

Данное расширение устанавливается через утилиту pecl

```
sudo pecl install gmagick-2.0.4RC1
```

Для работы расширения может потребоваться пакет graphicsmagick. 
Установка

```
sudo apt-get install graphicsmagick
```

Спасибо за "пищу для ума". Собственно комманда для установки всех необходимых библиотек, для работы gmagick с освновными форматами изображаений (JPEG, PNG,TIFF)

```
sudo apt-get install libtool bzip2 zlib1g ghostscript gsfonts libfreetype6 libjpeg8 libjasper1 libpng12-0 libtiff5 graphicsmagick libgraphicsmagick1-dev
```

Если необходимо, дам ссылку на материал где описываю процесс установки в результате которой gmagick без ошибок работает с JPEG и PNG

Здесь описано в деталях, что делал, в результате чего все заработало http://hh-pc.blogspot.com/2017/11/gmagick-php-ubuntu.html

Comment: не помогло. **Fatal error: Uncaught GmagickException: No decode delegate for this image format**.

Comment: libjpeg8 у Вас установлен?

Comment: не знаю? Как проверить? Вероятно нет.

Comment: Для корректной работы graphicsmagick с jpeg форматами нужно 2 быблитеки libjpeg8 и libjasper1 Проверить можно при помощи комманды dpkg -l | grep libjpeg8 и dpkg -l | grep libjasper1 Если он не установленны - нужно установить и скорее всего пондобится переустановить graphicsmagick

Comment: Как их установить?? Как установить другие библиотеки??

Comment: sudo apt-get install libjpeg8 libjasper1

Comment: А как узнать какие библиотеки еще нужно дополнительно, для PDF и PHG может где почитать можно??

Comment: @ Антон Скородумов Еще япользовался инструкцие вот такой http://odware.livejournal.com/477.html  вот такой http://www.graphicsmagick.org/INSTALL-unix.html Но  на компьютере все пеерекодурует а через сервер на который я установил ка видно из картинки. Не хватает форматов для декодирования. Что делать подробно можете описать? А то не понятно.

Comment: Ответ дополнил, пробуйте.

Comment: Да добавь ссылку. Чет ничего не выходит пока? Возможно из за дистрибутива Lubuntu

Comment: Желательно ошибку и вывод gm version

Comment: Ошибка та же. Я переустановил все еще раз, и перезагрузил сервер. Но то же самое. Ошибку смотри в исходиниках, вопроса

Comment: gm version, что выводит?  А так же вывод dpkg -l | grep "jasper\|jpeg\|libtool"

Comment: Дополнил вопрос там все что тебя интрересует

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, то Вам осталось только переустановить graphicsmagick. Я б его удалил полностью, а поставил не по инструкции которую вы указывали, а при помощи sudo apt-get install graphicsmagick